# Win32 API like CreateProcess, but works on bat/cmd/etc. (i.e. uses PATHEXT)

Tags: winapi, createprocess

If you use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it only works on .exe's, [apparently](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2318#issuecomment-7465665). What's the best way to make this work with other executable file types?

The best we have so far is to prepend `cmd /c` to such cases. Is that really the correct approach?

Comment: Are you talking about [`SHellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Amazed I don't think that would work; I need the ability to e.g. send input and capture output from the process, which I get with `CreateProcess` via the `PPROCESS_INFORMATION` structure.

Comment: `CreateProcess()` by its nature works only with executable files (which normally include batch files). Anything else is a "document" and has a custom handler that you can invoke with `ShellExecute()`.

Comment: `ShellExecuteEx` doesn't have the ability to redirect stdio handles, which `CreateProcess` does via `STARTUPINFO`'s `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, and `hStdError` handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch files aren't technically executable files, they are just registered to open with `cmd`. As you mention that you need the ability to manipulate I/O handles, your best bet is indeed to use `CreateProcess` with `cmd /c`.